# How to make the Displacement Map Texture and Material Texture Match?

Tags: texturing, materials, displacement, normal-map

I added a image texture  to a simple sphere by creating a new material and selecting "image" as the color.
Then I used the displacement modifier to make a displacement map. I selected the very same image as the displacement texture.

I want the displacement surface to be exactly the same mapping as the material surface. Where material is dark, the displacement should go inward, and vice versa.

However the displacement texture and the material texture do not coincide[image: 3D window capture].

I cannot use the shader nodes as I want to export the model to stl file for 3D printing.

How do I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question with a picture of the shader node for this material?

Comment: See how to upload an image to a post - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hi i did not use any shader mode as I want to export this model as 3D printing. I want to use the texture on the model to create a textured surface on the 3D model.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the same scale and use the same coordinates for both textures.

Alternatively you can use a mapping node to fix the scale and rotation problem.

Comment: Thanks susu. Not an English native speaker.

Comment: Hello Purus. How do you change the scale and coordinate for the texture?Sorry I am a blender noob I only know how to select the file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out how to do it at last.

All I need to do is to just select "Texture Coordinate" = UV in the Displacement Modifier Options
[![Solution][1]][1]

Thanks a lot guys! =)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpkSk.png